# Algorithms and procedures to recover objects and morphisms from the properties of category?

Tags: logic, category-theory

Let C be a category and let us have many diagrams, that give properties of this category, e.g. existence of limits, existence of pentagon identities, existence of monoidal or other algebra like structures. So, are there algorithms or procedures, how can we recover the more or less concrete content of objects and morphisms of this category? Take for example Institution, which is structure, that characterizes syntax and all possible models of some logic. This structure involves the category of signatures. Can we use properties of institution to recover signatures. I.e. can we define category and only after then recover the objects and morphisms?

Comment: Your question is unclear. How do you propose to first define a category and only then get the objects and morphisms when the definition of category requires the objects and morphisms? (a variant only requires morphisms, but still). You'll need to clarify what you actually mean. As it stands, this question is likely to get closed.

Comment: There are lot of logics and even more can be devised. Institution theory is the tool to classify logics, path ti universal logic. So, new logic firstly can be defined as category with excellent properties and only later the concrete synax can be recovered by recovering objects. Is this possible? This is top-down approch, opposit to the traditional bottom-up approach.

Comment: The actions suggested in my post provides the application of category theory, always welcome idea. It is not good idea to close question because of ignorance of uneillgnes to explore new ideas.

Comment: In essence - what can we say about objects and morphisms of arbitrary category from the existence of different diagrams, universal properties etc. On the category? Are there some good references in literature?

Comment: You're trying to see what information on objects and morphisms you can get from the knowledge that a category $C$ has certain types of limits and algebraic structure, is that it ?

Comment: Max, exactly so. But I expect, that category will have quite rich structure, so, the form of objects and morphisms will be quite constrained and not too abstract. Actually I wonder why there are so many close votes. In what sense my question is so crazy?

Comment: It's just very vague. So for instance, the property that $C$ is the free cocomplete category containing an object tells us that $C$ is the category of sets. The syntactic category of a logic, somewhat similarly, is supposed to be the initial category admitting the interpretation of that logic. But this is just characterizing things by universal properties-is this what you're getting at?

Comment: Yes, this is exactly so. Even more - what can we deduce about objects and morphisms of category which admist monadic functor or similar or more complex algebraic structure. What can we deduce about objects and morphisms of category which is Elenberg-Moore or Kleisli category and so on, the objects and morphisms can be constrained by the set of properties and algebras on categories.

Answer (score 0):

Based on my limited knowledge in the area, and judging by typical expert responses to the question so far, this issue seems to be completely unanticipated by the existing expertise, and by all likelihood, there's no body of knowledge dedicated specifically to the kind of problem that it presents.

You may want to have a look at [Computational Category Theory](http://www.cs.man.ac.uk/~david/categories/book/book.pdf) by Rydeheard and Burstall, if you haven't already.  For what I remember of it, its approach might be somewhat askew for your purpose, but a lot of it would probably apply.